# Android Studio, problemas con JavaMail

Tags: android-studio, email

Llevo varios días con un problema tratando de enviar un correo con la libreria JavaMail y no encuentro la solución, cuando intento enviar con correo con mi aplicación en AndroidStudio, me sale el siguiente error "javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465". Ya he intentado varias cosas como cambiar el puerto por el 587. Se les ocurre algo mas que pueda intentar?

Aquí mi codigo.

```js
private Button b_enviar;
    EditText et_sugerencia;

    private String correoE;
    private String contraseñaE;
    private String correoR;
    private String contraseñaR;

    Session session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregar_recetas);
        setTitle("Agrega una receta");

        correoE= "correoRecibir@gmail.com";
        contraseñaE="********";

        b_enviar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_enviar);
        et_sugerencia=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_sugerenciareceta);

        b_enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                Properties properties=new Properties();
//Declaracion de puertos
                properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                try{

                    session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
                        @Override
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(correoE,contraseñaE);
                        }
                    });

                    if(session!=null){

                        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(correoE));
                        message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("correoenviar@gmail.com"));
                        message.setSubject("Probando el titulo");
                        message.setText(b_enviar.getText().toString());
                       // message.setContent(b_enviar.getText().toString(),"text/html; charset=utf-8");
                        crearToast("Llegue aqui");
                        Transport.send(message);
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Si tienen preguntas las contestare lo mas rápido que pueda

Comment: Valida que no haya un firewall bloqueando las conexiones. Prueba hacer un telnet a esa url por ese puerto.

Comment: Puedo intentarlo desactivando mi Firewall?

Comment: Sí, prueba desactivando para saber si influye o no. Si estás en windows, revisa que la conexión no esté identificada como pública.

Comment: No es el Firewall, lo desactive y aun así me saltaba el mismo error. Entonces eso se descarta.